# How to read from a .txt file in a C Console Program?

Tags: c, file, console, user-input

I have a program where I have to read from user input to get a list of data pairs, such as:

```
1,2 3,4 5,6
```

or:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
4,3
```

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

int partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high];    // pivot 
    int i = (low - 1);  // Index of smaller element 

    for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)
    {
        // If current element is smaller than the pivot 
        if (arr[j] < pivot)
        {
            i++;    // increment index of smaller element 
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        /* pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now
           at right place */
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

        // Separately sort elements before 
        // partition and after partition 
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

}
int main()
{
    int n1, n2;
    int x[10] = { 0 };
    int y[10] = { 0 };

    int capacity = 0;

    int n = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {

        scanf_s(" %d , %d [^\n]", &n1, &n2);
            x[i] = n1;
            y[i] = n2;

    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        printf("%d , %d\n", x[j], y[j]);

    }
    quickSort(x, 0, n-1);
    printArray(x, n);

    printf("Minimum is: %d", x[0]);
    printf("Maximum is: %d", x[n-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to pipe a file into the console by running a command in CMD:
program.exe some.txt

it will give me:

```
-858993460 , -858993460
-858993460 , -858993460
...
```

But when I type the values from the txt file in, I get the proper output.

Is there anyway to let a C Console program to accept user input and .txt file?

My prof showed an example using scanf_s where he can just use the debug.exe and txt file to get the input, he said it tricks the program into thinking it came from the keyboard buffer.
I am confused on how this would work.

Error Codes From CMD:

> C:\Users\username\Downloads\Project\test_files>sort.exe book.txt -> sort.exe < book.txt

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

The other error is a red pop up saying I should get a FInal Version (it's a pop up from windows).

Comment: `program.exe some.txt` -> `program.exe < some.txt`

Comment: I get an access denied/other process is using error

Comment: Please show the _verbatin_ error message as well as the _verbatim_ command you type in cmd.[Edikt]  your question and put all relevant information _there_. Also transform your code into a [MCVE] by adding the #includes.

Comment: I provided my code and the error messages I got. Please have a look

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve]. [Edit] your post to include enough source code that we can compile it.  It can also help if you tell us how you compile and link it.  What exactly do you expect `scanf_s(" %d , %d [^\n]", &n1, &n2);` to do?

Comment: I am trying to read a list of real number pairs. So 1,2 3,4 5,6 7,8...etc. Either from user input, which works atm, or piped in from a .txt file, which does not work.

Comment: What do you think the format string `" %d , %d [^\n]"` does?

Comment: read the input in that format, and the second part after the comma read an integer and read until it hits a newline character?

Comment: _" a red pop up saying I should get a FInal Version "_ you need to show us the _verbatim_ error message.

Comment: "This app cannot run on your PC, To find a version for your PC, check with software publisher"

Comment: _""This app cannot run on your PC, To find a version for your PC, check with softwar"_: this is probably not related to your question, it rather looks like a problem of your installation, it might be an obsolete anti virus program or some other crap you have installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Your command line is wrong.

Instead of:

```
sort.exe < book.txt -> sort.exe < book.txt
```

you want:

```
sort.exe < book.txt | sort.exe > book2.txt
```

But anyway I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do here...

Be aware that that you need an other file `book2.txt` instead of `book.txt`, that's the reason for the `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` error.